# Require in require javascript

Tags: javascript

I made a nice folder structure with the use of require and require in require in javascript. As the require in require needs all functions to be included again I was wondering if there are easier ways to do this.

```
var file2 = require('./file2.js');

var IncludeAll={
        func1: function(msg){
            return file2.function1(msg);
        },
        func2: function(msg){
            return file2.function2(msg);
        }
};

module.exports = IncludeAll;
```

Comment: I don't see any nested requires. What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a exporter script "exporter.js" file like below.

```
// exporter.js
module.exports = {
   File2: require('./file2'),
   File3: require('./file3')
}
```

Then you can import and call like this.

```
const {File2} = require('./exporter')
const param = 5;
File2.func1(param);
File2.func2(param);
```